# Reading a file that is still being written / copied by some other program

Tags: java, file-io

I have a file watcher application which notifies my java class when a new file is created in a folder. I have a cronjob that copies the file in the folder whenever the file is ready. These files are huge (30 Million lines)  so it takes a while for copying file to complete. But my file watcher app notifies as soon as the file is created so in such cases following code throws IOException

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
```

Is there a way I can open the file in "read" mode so it doesn't crash when the file is being used by something else ?  I saw a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15200396/reading-a-file-content-while-it-hasnt-finished-being-copied-uploaded)  but there's no good answer.   This seems like a simple enough use case for java to support but I can't find a solution.

Comment: Could you use semaphores? If your notifier has to wait to acquire a semaphore then that might take care of it. Is it necessary that the notifier start as soon as the file is created?

Comment: Can you elaborate how I can use semaphore here ?  the program that copies the files is a shell script executed thru a cronjob...  and watcher (notifier) is actually a commons-io library that provides folder monitor functionality...

Comment: What if you created a 0 byte file and called it sem or something similarly descriptive whenever a file is accessing things. You could even call it semFILENAME where FILENAME is the file you're accessing. If everything is checking for it before accessing the file it might work. You'd have to control when processes sleep if the file exists though

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how much control you have over the process that is writing the file. But you might want to use a convention to help your file polling process know when  the file has been completely written.

Some commons conventions.

- Write the file with the data, then write another empty file with the same name and a .rdy extension. The poller looks for the rdy file then goes after the real file using the name.
- Write the file with the data with an extension like .tmp or .writing then rename it after you are done writing all of the data. The poller ignores files with a .tmp (or .writing) extension.